# memoir & biblatex: How to control alignment of bibliography entry in table of contents?

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, formatting, memoir

By default, the bibliography entry produced by `biblatex` in the table of contents of my `memoir` document is aligned with the chapter title.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
  @book{somebook,
    author={some author},
    title={some title}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\begin{refsection}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\textcite{somebook}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

How can I get the bibliography entry aligned with the title of the section headings? That is, how can I get the "R" in "References" aligned with the "A" in "A section"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (added to the preamble) ought to do it

```
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \if@twoside\markright{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}\fi
  \ifmemoirbibintoc
  {\phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}#1}}
  {}}

\makeatother
```

found in `biblatex.def`. I added the `\numberline{}` part.

Though, personally I prefer the default formatting.

Note that in `biblatex.def` there are two branches for `memoir`, depending on the `article` option is used or not. I just searched for `\addcontentsline` as that is the standard method for writing to the TOC.

Comment: Thanks, this does the job. (My reasoning is that the bibliography is like a section in the chapter, so it's title should be aligned with the titles of other (numbered) sections.)

Comment: @user1362373 To me, the indentation from your image is enough to indicate that this is part of the chapter.